# How to force a personal Union in EU3?

Tags: europa-universalis-3

What the title says. To be specific, I am playing as England and claimed the throne of Castile (going for a British-run Western European Block and Castille is much easier a dog to fight than France initially). I have a royal marriage with the Castillians and I claimed their throne to get a free Cassus Belli. I currently have sieged down nearly all of their provinces and when I open the peace deal interface, the option to force a personal union is not showing up.

I am playing In Nomine on steam, latest patches and version and such. I spent half of my army and my nation is severely exhausted from the War (Castile blitzed Portugal and I had to save their butts because they were "my" foothold on the continent if I lost the war and it would have been disastrous if Castile took half of their provinces). It would be a major waste if I could not get the desired PU on them and only some provinces.

I read on the EU3 Wiki that I might have to wait for a succession crisis to demand a PU, but there does not appear to be an interface to see if they are having a succession crisis. I am sure this was improved in Heir to the Throne, but alas I am broke right now so it does not appear that I will be able to get it at least until school start. Thanks in advance.

If it is just my inability to find the interface for the succession crisis feature, I would prefer a visual or something showing me where to look for it. I also checked my message settings five times over and can not find the message that the EU3 wiki spoke of.

Answer (score 1):

That is strange. TO make it clear, I don't remember IN, I recently played only DW. But if htere is Claim Throne CB and you used it to declare war, it should be there a term in offer peace deal. Normally it is located in last tab of the peace deal, where you can choose "Conceal Defeat", "Vassalise", in certain cases "Force Religion" and so on. There should be option that is called something like "Form a Personal Union".

I used it with spies mostly, but it doesn't matter how you get the proper CB. If you used it, option should be there. Are you sure you used teh correct CB, beause if not the option won't be visible?

And to answer the question fully how to do it, there are 3 ways:

1. Simple it may happen if you have royal marriages. You should be bigger, high prestige, positive relations... and it helps if you have more troops (indirectly, because if you have less troops, nation will try to break union). If you click on any province of another nation, hover over the ruler and you will see who is heir and what happens when ruler dies. If you are married to ruler with no heir it will say that upon rulrs death nation forms union with someone. If no proper royal marriage exists for this, then it will say some noble will take over (meaning AI will spawn someone to take over since nation won't disappear). I think union may happen even if heir exists, with lower odds on right conditions (heir has low legitimacy, you have great relations, you have much bigger prestige and legitimacy and so on)
2. What you did: under some conditions you can claim the thore if you have royal marriage. If two or more countries claim it, on death there will be Succession crisis war (you can't start succession war via option in interface). You get CB for one year upon claiming, so you may declare war on target country directly, with necessary stability hit for attacking a nation which you have marriage with. Warscore for force-forming PU is always 90%.
3. Use spy to fabricate claim and get Casus Belli like you get with Claim Throne option. Difference is that it costs you a spy, gold, reputation if spy is discovered and it may not even succedd, but you avoid stability hit on declaring war.

To keep UN runnning on your ruler's death, make sure you have positive relations. And it will surely be negative after the war, so expect to send gifts, guaranties, allow troops etc. So it is bad idea to start UN war with old ruler as he may die just when war is over and that would disband UN. You would get one year CB for UN restoration, but you might still be in cease-fire. So it is better to start with new young ruler or start with old one, but wait for him to die before you sign peace deal. Also, what was said before, if nation has more troops than you or simply feel they are big enough, they will spam you with insult to lower your relations and wait for UN to break. This won't happen while you are at war though. So sometimes a small nation with big legitimacy may end up with big nations in UN simply through marriages. The big nation will start spamming insults unless you declare a war and keep using their troops to expand until you are big enough to keep them in UN. Naturally it is dangerous to be in constant war, but it might be worth it.

Comment: Legitimacy and actual heirs are introduced in Heir to the Throne, up until then there is a base chance of a regency upon ruler death, with a base chance of coming under a PU, both being modifiable by things such as number of royal marriages and such. At least that is what the wiki says. I did use the correct CB, though before HttT you cannot select "war-goals" (meaning that if you have a CB in general and DoW you dont get the relations penalty). I will admit the CB system is a little hard for me to understand in this version ;)

Comment: And there is a "form-union" peace option, but it is greyed out for some reason making me wonder what is wrong. Most guides suggest forming unions is the best way to expand as conquest drastically raises infamy.

Comment: Oh, I forgot how it went with versions :) Anyway, it is strange that option is there and greyed out. Yes, unions are best for expnading, especially in later version with much higher infamy penalties. But in IN (IIRC) it is not so much, unless you are really going for simple conquest of entire world. I would keep lot of vassals though, but with Castille being too big and homogene, it is better to impose union. Sorry I can't help you, I'm not sure what is wrong either.

Comment: One more thing: France is harder to get than Castille, which means to actually take on France before Castille. They swallow their vassals and expand east, forming huge armies. I like stopping them first (well, first among the other big ones) and just force them to release smaller nations. If Castille swallows half Portugal and Aragorn, you swallow the rest and force Castille to release the rest of teritories. Castille usually holds 2 or 3 stacks of 15k troops and are involved in Africa. You can easily beat them on the sea and lock them in Africa or let them bring back one stack at the time.

Comment: Not going for a global conquest, just Iberia, France, Germany, and Italy + New World and some Chinese and Indian colonies. France has been having a hard time, and has fought three alliances including Austria in the last decade and had to release Provence and Normandy (actually Austria ended up peacefully vassalizing Normandy). Its a shame Austria is my "rival" and hates me because of an early game fiasco involving Danish aggression calling me into a HRE war, because if I was allied to Austria we would have dogpiled France first ;). France has also swallowed half of Aragon.

Comment: And In Nomine infamy is ~1 per province taken in a peace deal and per vassalization and 6 infamy per annexation. It would be exceedingly prohibitive to conquer castile as it is 15 provinces. This means ~15 infamy or 2 decades of lowering it. And a game of EU3 without constant warfare on some front can get really boring.